# How do I use beta in meta-analysis?

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size

I am completely new to meta analyses and I have to do one for a university project.
I basically have beta coefficients from different papers performing covariate methods such as partial least squares, and want to pool the results together to assess the effect of different factors on each other.

However, since only correlation coefficients ($r$) have suitable effect sizes, I have an issue because all of my papers presented results of path coefficients (i.e. $\beta$). I read a paper from [Peterson & Brown (2005)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/8089245_On_the_Use_of_Beta_Coefficients_in_Meta-Analysis) about how I can convert $\beta$ to $r$.

My question is:

1. What effect size should I use? Should I convert them to Fisher’s $z$?
2. Another common effect size is Hedges’ $g$; however it seems like I would need two treatment groups to use Hedges’ $g$. How should I approach this?
3. Some research papers present correlation coefficients, however for “validity testing” rather than actual results. Can I use these correlation coefficients instead?

Basically, am I going the right direction?

Comment: Why not use the $\beta$s with their standard error? However the main problem here seems to be the issue of whether the models from which they come are comparable as, if they are not, you are mixing apples and lemons.